# How do I find out what my IP Address of my MySQL host is?

Tags: mysql, ip, host

I have a free domain running at x10hosting (x10.bz), and I want to find out the IP Address of my MySQL host for it, so I can contact the MySQL database from another host. I've already added that host to the access list, but now I need to find out the IP Address of the MySQL host. How can I find this out? x10 is using cPanel X and PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The SQL query `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'` will show you the hostname of the MySQL server which you can easily resolve to its IP address.

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port'` Will give you the port number.

You can find details about this in MySQL's manual: [12.4.5.41. SHOW VARIABLES Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-variables.html) and [5.1.4. Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html)

Comment: My hostname says `ubuntu`. How do I check the IP address of that?

Comment: information_schema equivalent: `select * from information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES where VARIABLE_NAME like 'hostname';`

Comment: I don't understand how hostname can supposedly be resolved to an IP address. Mine is running on docker so the hostname is jibberish.

Comment: Add `;` at the end of the query like so: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';`

Comment: Sorry but how does this have 56 upvotes and accepted? The Q is "how to get IP" and this answer is "here's how to get hostname" and a hint that you could convert it to IP.

Answer (score 20):

You may try this if using MySQL 5.7 version

```
 mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1) AS ip,  @@hostname as hostname, @@port as port, DATABASE() as current_database;
+-----------+-----------------+------+------------------+
| ip        | hostname        | port | current_database |
+-----------+-----------------+------+------------------+
| localhost | host001         | 3306 | kakadba          |
+-----------+-----------------+------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or just write status in mysql prompt

```
mysql> \s
```

OR

```
 mysql> status
```

Answer (score 7):

Using PHPMyAdmin all variables are already listed if you click "home" > "MySQL system variables". You can use the find feature of your browser to search for the "hostname" and the "port" variables or scroll to them. It's listed in alphabetical order. No mucking about with queries if you are a non technical person.

Answer (score 4):

Once you are in **phpMyAdmin**, look for the horizontal menu:

Dashboard | Sql | Status | Users ...etc

Click on  **Variables**.

Here you will find all the variables for mySql server.  You can try the search box for specific variables.

Good Luck.